# Why does my $().hover get triggered multiple times?

Tags: jquery

I have a div containing other divs, I want each div to flip once upon `.mouseenter()` and then go back to it's original loacation upon `.mouseleave()` therefore I have used the `.toggleClass()` method to append a class to an element and then remove it when the item is no longer hovered over.

This works, however if I pass the over all elements then it seems like the event handling for `.hover()` is carried out mutliple times, why is this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".square").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("flipper");
  });
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  background: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="color:orange; background:blue; width:1000px; height:120px;">
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
  <div class="square"> </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** **To reproduce the issue try hovering over many items rather than waite for the animation to finish, keep on scrolling the mouse from right to left or vice versa at various speeds. It would seem as some div's flip multiple times.**

I am also able to reproduce this on various browsers.

Comment: Try use `mouseover` and not `hover`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I already attempted to do this and the outcome was no different :(

Comment: @Abs what should happen when you hover and leave out of box?

Comment: @krishnar at the moment it would just go back to how it was before the .flipper class existed which is what it does

Comment: @Abs  see my solution. You should get now whats happening with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason** :

Whenever you hover over div, div starts flipping.While flipping its height starts reducing and your cursor even though in same position, mouseleave event occurs as height of div completely reduced to small and now cursor is out of its area.

To reproduce this error try to reduce transition and hover

**Solution**

Create outer div that match with square div and make it hide so that it dimension wont change. Now whenver you hover only square div dimension changes but not outer div.And by the way we write mouse events on outerdiv.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".outer").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".square").toggleClass("flipper");
  });
  $(".outer").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".square").toggleClass("flipper");
  });
});
```

```css
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  background: white;

}

.outer{
 background: grey;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
 
}

.flipper {
  transition: 2s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="color:orange; background:blue; width:1000px; height:120px;">
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
  <div class="outer"><div class="square"> </div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first thing is that you do not need jquery for such animations. you can do it with css only. i have implemented your css. have a look below.

```
        .square {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      color: black;
      background: white;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .square:hover {
      transition: 0.6s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
```

just paste this css into your file and remove the javaScript it will work perfectly

Comment: Still there, please attempt to reproduce as per my guidlines in my question

Answer (score 0):

try below codes.. its working fine.

```
      .square {
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
      max-height: 100px;
      background: #fff;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    .flipper {
      transition: .5s;
      transform-style: preserve-3d;
      transform: rotateX(180deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }


  <div style="color:orange; background:blue; width:1000px; height:120px;">
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$(".square").mouseover(function() {
  if( $(this).hasClass("flipper") )
  {
      $(this).removeClass("flipper");
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("flipper");
  }
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have applied hover event handler to square class. So it is going to call handler for all div element which has square class on hovering. Because of that it is getting called multiple time. Hope this will help you.